# Reducing BitmapDrawable size

Tags: android, android-drawable

I am reducing size of images with this function:

```
Drawable reduceImageSize (String path) 
{
    BitmapDrawable bit1 = (BitmapDrawable) Drawable.createFromPath(path);
    Bitmap bit2 = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bit1.getBitmap(), 640, 360, true);
    BitmapDrawable bit3 = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(),bit2);
    return bit3;
}
```

And its working fine, the only problem is when I call this function multiple time the app is getting slow, is there any way to optimize this function? Maybe reducing size via matrix?
Also I am reading images from SD Card and need the back as Drawable for animations, and this function provides this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `BitmapFactory.Options` and `inJustDecodeBounds` to scale it down:

`Bitmap bitmap = getBitmapFromFile(path, width, height);`

```
public static Bitmap getBitmapFromFile(String path, int width, int height) {
    final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
    BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path, options);

    // Calculate inSampleSize
    options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options, width, height);

    options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path, options);
    return bitmap;
}

public static int calculateInSampleSize(BitmapFactory.Options options, int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {
    // Raw height and width of image
    final int height = options.outHeight;
    final int width = options.outWidth;
    int inSampleSize = 1;

    if (height > reqHeight || width > reqWidth) {
        if (width > height) {
            inSampleSize = Math.round((float)height / (float)reqHeight);
        } else {
            inSampleSize = Math.round((float)width / (float)reqWidth);
        }
    }
    return inSampleSize;
}
```

Read more about it here: [Loading Large Bitmaps Efficiently](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html)

Also, I'm not sure where you are calling this method but if you have many of them please make sure you are caching the Bitmaps using `LruCache` or similar: [Caching Bitmaps](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/cache-bitmap.html)