# OutOfMemoryError when using 2 bitmaps

Tags: android, android-layout, bitmap, out-of-memory

I have 2 `ImageView` on my home layout and their content comes from images placed on SD card as shown in below code snippet:

```
try {
        String tempPath1 = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                + File.separator + "Clipping_Pictures" + File.separator
                + "06-05-2013_02-06-09pm.png";
        File f = new File(tempPath1);
        Bitmap b = null, b2 = null;
        b = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(f.getPath());

        if (f.exists()) {
            ivClip1.setImageBitmap(b);//ivClip1 is ImageView
        }

        tempPath1 = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                + File.separator + "Clipping_Pictures" + File.separator
                + "06-05-2013_02-06-33pm.png";
        f = new File(tempPath1);
        b2 = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(f.getPath());

        if (f.exists()) {
            ivClip2.setImageBitmap(b2);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

When I load the app for the 1st time, it displays both the images on respective imageviews. But 2nd launch on-wards, app crashes with following exception:
*OutOfMemoryError: bitmap size exceeds VM budget*

**Note that** two resource images are *.png* and of size ~850kb each which should be fine I guess.

There are similar threads on SO and on internet and I tried some of their suggested solutions, but none seems to work.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: 'Note that two resource images are .png and of size ~850kb' it does no matter. What matter is width and height of your bitmap

Comment: It's approx.  2000x2600

Comment: every bitmap will require approx 20MB of memory. A bitmap will require width*heigth*4 bytes of memory

Comment: Can you let me know how you came to this figure : 20MB ???

Comment: You should call  'recycle()' method for each bitmap when you close your app or close the activity if you don't need anymore.

Comment: Have you tried this? (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16915619/reducing-bitmapdrawable-size/16915719#16915719)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/477572/strange-out-of-memory-issue-while-loading-an-image-to-a-bitmap-object. scale down the image

Comment: @GAMA I update my previous comment

Comment: @onurtaskin : but I'm having issue in launching the app. So how does `recycle` will help?

Comment: @KenWolf : What should I specify as height and width if I want to display those images as thumbnails in my app.

Comment: The height and width of the thumbnails you require, for example try 100x100. I don't know of course. Only you know your requirements :)

Comment: @Raghunandan : that answer mentions `REQUIRED_SIZE=70`. What does **70** signifies here.

Comment: @GAMA check the comment above the line " The new size we want to scale to". Mention what you require

Comment: @Raghunandan : Ok. Image will be 70x70 in that case then?

Comment: @GAMA i have not tried the code. yup should be. check the docs. http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

its because of large size of your bitmaps. compress your bitmap using following code:

```
Bitmap ShrinkBitmap(byte[] file, int width, int height){

         BitmapFactory.Options bmpFactoryOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            bmpFactoryOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(file, 0, file.length, bmpFactoryOptions);


            int heightRatio = (int)Math.ceil(bmpFactoryOptions.outHeight/(float)height);
            int widthRatio = (int)Math.ceil(bmpFactoryOptions.outWidth/(float)width);

            if (heightRatio > 1 || widthRatio > 1)
            {
             if (heightRatio > widthRatio)
             {
              bmpFactoryOptions.inSampleSize = heightRatio;
             } else {
              bmpFactoryOptions.inSampleSize = widthRatio;
             }
            }

            bmpFactoryOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
            bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(file, 0, file.length, bmpFactoryOptions);
         return bitmap;
        }
```

Comment: 1st parameter is `byte[] file`. If I'm sending `Bitmap bitmap`, then `Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(file, 0, file.length, bmpFactoryOptions);` will change to `Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bitmap, bmpFactoryOptions);` , right?

Comment: m sorry but I don't have much idea about chat session. Can you give me the chat link?

Comment: you havnt chat experience.??

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/31249/discussion-between-gama-and-segi)

Answer (score 3):

If you are building your app for Android 3.0 on wards, then you can use  `android:largeHeap="true"` attribute in your application tag of manifest file.
Doing this, hope your app won't crash due to Out of Memory.

Here is example:

application

```
android:allowBackup="true"
android:icon="@drawable/icon_96x96"
android:label="@string/app_name"
android:largeHeap="true"
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"
```

Thanks!

Comment: Oh pity. Minimum support for my app is v2.2 :(

Answer (score 1):

Are you executing all this code from onCreate() or from onResume()?

You may try to clean the views before you try to load the images again (ivClip1.setImageBitmap(null) or a lightweight one), because while you are decoding both bitmaps you are still having the previous instances in memory while showing.

Comment: in `onCreate()`. What do u mean by clean the views?

Comment: I suggested calling ivClip1.setImageBitmap(null), if that doesn't work, you may try to set a little empty image (for example a marker image that may say "loading") ivClip1.setImageResource(R.drawable.my_little_marker_image);

Answer (score 1):

You can add this lines to resize bitmap and then use it

```
BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
options.inSampleSize = 8;
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(file),null,options);
```

Method to calculate samplesize and reduce the bitmap size

```
private Bitmap decodeFile(File f){
    try {
        BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        o.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f),null,o);

        final int REQUIRED_SIZE=70;

        //Find the correct scale value. It should be the power of 2.
        int scale=1;
        while(o.outWidth/scale/2>=REQUIRED_SIZE && o.outHeight/scale/2>=REQUIRED_SIZE)
            scale*=2;

        BitmapFactory.Options o2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        o2.inSampleSize=scale;
        return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f), null, o2);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {}
    return null;
}
```

Comment: how does you reach this **8**?

Comment: it is hardcoded, if you dont want to hardcode 8 then see the edited answer.

Comment: it's similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16915619/reducing-bitmapdrawable-size/16915719#16915719 right????